# Is every $R^iF(M)$ isomorphic to some $F(N)$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian categories. Assume that $A$ has enough injectives. Is there a "useful" (take that to mean what you will) condition on $A$ and $B$ such that the following is true?

> For all left exact $F\colon A\to B$, for all $M\in A$, and for all $i$ (equiv. for $i=1$), there's an $N \in A$ with $R^i F(M)\cong F(N)$?